# React component communication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, material-ui

I've been writing a prototype in React with Material UI the past two weeks and I'm really enjoying it!

Until now I've always put all my components in my main class to get the hang out of and didn't think much of component communication.

My problem is that I don't know how to tell a component that I imported, to enable/disabled one if its buttons.

In my case, I import a Stepper in my main class and want to disable the "NEXT" button if a series of state values in the main class have not been set yet.

So, first of all, I have to choose my dispenser, then the next button gets enabled and disabled again until I choose my fuel type, then again disable the "NEXT" button until the amount has been chosen and then just finish the fueling.

The Stepper is just the [demo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/docs/src/pages/demos/steppers/HorizontalLinearAlternativeLabelStepper.js) you can find on the Material ui website.

My state in the main class looks like this:

```
    fuelDispenser: 0,
    fuelDispenserChosen: false,

    fuelType: '',
    fuelTypeChosen: false,

    fuelAmount: 0,
    fuelAmountChosen: false,
```

And I'm calling the Stepper right next to my table with all the dispensers listed.

```
<div className="row center-xs">
    <div className="col-xs-6">
      <Paper>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Dispenser Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Status</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Fueling</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {this.state.dispensers.map(dispenser => {
              return(
                <TableRow key={dispenser.uid}>
                  <TableCell>{dispenser.description}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{dispenser.status}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{
                    <Button 
                      variant="raised" 
                      color="primary" 
                      type="submit"
                    > START
                    </Button> 
                  }
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </Paper>
    </div>

    <div className="col-md-6">
      <FuelingStepper />
    </div>
```

If someone could explain to me how I could pass my props to the component, even on a different example, I'd be really glad. I know I could do something like,

```
<FuelingStepper fuelDispenserChosen={fuelDispenserChosen} 
                fuelTypeChosen={fuelTypeChosen} 
                fuelAmountChosen={fuelAmountChosen}
/>
```

but I don't get it how to handle all three of them in the Stepper class.

Comment: with my understanding, you need to pass props/state from table to FuelingStepper ?  It would be helpful if you share your two components

Comment: @Jayaval The FuelingStepper is just the unedited demo from Material UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the state variable as a props like below.

```
 <FuelingStepper fuelDispenserChosen={this.state.fuelDispenserChosen} 
            fuelTypeChosen={this.state.fuelTypeChosen} 
            fuelAmountChosen={this.state.fuelAmountChosen} />
```

And in the `FuelingStepper` component you can use get these values using `this.props` like below.

```
 this.props.fuelDispenserChosen
 this.props.fuelTypeChosen
 this.props.fuelAmountChosen
```

I have created a small example for you for showing how to pass the state variable and get it in another component.

```
  class Hello extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);        
        this.state = {
          fuelDispenserChosen: 'false',
          fuelTypeChosen: 'true',
          fuelAmountChosen: 'false'
         };
      }
      render() {
        return (
           <div>
               <h1>Hello {this.props.name}</h1> 
               <FuelingStepper fuelDispenserChosen={this.state.fuelDispenserChosen} 
                               fuelTypeChosen={this.state.fuelTypeChosen} 
                               fuelAmountChosen={this.state.fuelAmountChosen} />
           </div>                
         )          
       }
  }
  class FuelingStepper extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
         <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Fuel Dispenser Chosen</td>
              <td>{this.props.fuelDispenserChosen}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Fuel Type Chosen</td>
              <td>{this.props.fuelTypeChosen}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>Fuel Amount Chosen</td>
             <td>{this.props.fuelAmountChosen}</td>
            </tr>
         </table>  
        )          
     }
  }


  ReactDOM.render(
      <Hello name="James" />,
             document.getElementById('container')
  );
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/102357/)

Comment: Okay, that helps a bit. Although I still don't know how to let's say press the "START" button like in my Table above `<TableCell>...<Button onClick={this.dispenserChosen}>...</Button>` and then step ahead with the Step component.

Comment: you mean to say after clicking the button only you want to show the Step component. Initially you don't to show it.

Comment: So, if I change my `this.state.fuelDispenserChosen` to `true`, the FuelingStepper gets rerendered with a different prop, moving the step by one forward, right?

Comment: Here's the [handleNext](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/docs/src/pages/demos/steppers/HorizontalLinearAlternativeLabelStepper.js) method.

Comment: I mean that pressing START should move the stepper by one ahead.

Comment: i mean do whatever you want on the button press, update your state value on your button press, so that it will automatically reflect in the Step component. I have just assigned true/false value. you can assign numbers if you want and increase on each click. so that updated value automatically passed to your step component.

Comment: I understand, but I don't want to do it with the button in FuelStepper but with a button I have in my main class. So essentially I want to access `handleNext`if I change my state (`this.state.fuelDispenserChosen` a boolean) in my main class. And then step one by one forward if I change the other states (`fuelTypeChosen` and `fuelAmountChosen`) - I do get it, that I have to handle that in the `handleNext` method in the FuelStepper. Maybe I'm drifting a bit off from my post, sorry.

Comment: So by doing what you said, taking the three boolean values as props in the `FuelingStepper` from the main class and then changing their values by `this.setState(...)`, I could access the `handleNext()` method, but only by calling it like this in the button in `FuelingStepper` -> `onClick={this.handleNext()}` - am I doing something I shouldn't, since I am getting a Warning: `Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render or another component's constructor)`